# Python - Two same functions in argument

Tags: python, json

I am trying to pass two arguments (KeepDuplicates and OrderDic) to Object_pairs_hooks, but don't know the pythonic way of doing it, can anyone help please?

```
 raw_data = json.loads(json_value, object_pairs_hook=KeepDuplicates, object_pairs_hook=OrderedDict)
```

KeepDuplicates - allows for duplicate JSON keys

OrderDic - Should organize the JSON in the same order as the input JSON

Thank you!!

Comment: you can not pass 2 keys which are the same

Comment: but you could write a function that calls KeepDuplicates and OrderDic on the decoded literal passed to it and returns the result afterwards. Then you would pass that function to object_pairs_hook

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`json.loads` creates a list of key/value pairs, and the default action is to apply `dict` to that and return it.  `object_pairs_hook` does whatever you want to the list instead of `dict`.

If you set `object_pairs_hook` to `lambda x: x` (just return each element as is), it will just return a list of key_value pairs in the order they are read.

```
>>> x = '{"3": 3, "0": 0, "1": 1, "2": 2, "3": 3, "4": 4}'
>>> json.loads(x, object_pairs_hook=lambda el: el)
[('3', 3), ('0', 0), ('1', 1), ('2', 2), ('3', 3), ('4', 4)]
```

You can then use your ordered key/value pairs to make any kind of object you please.  This will be a very effective way to keep order and keep duplicates. Unless you are creating your own object, I'm not aware of a dictionary-like class that accepts duplicate keys.  A list might be your best bet, or your own class.

```
class SillyClass(object):
    def __init__(self, a_list):
        self._list = a_list[:]
    def show(self):
        return self._list[:]

to_test = json.loads(x, object_pairs_hook=SillyClass)
print(to_test.show())
```

output => `[('3', 3), ('0', 0), ('1', 1), ('2', 2), ('3', 3), ('4', 4)]`

Comment: Thank you very much! Worked like a dream!